# Incorrect display in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer

Testing your first website http://sham62.ru/. In all browsers except IE 11, it displays correctly, but in IE 11 the style is not applied to the text, the address of the institution slips down. Please tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Because the way you write `@font-face` rule:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Aladdin;
    src: url(../fonts/aladdin.ttf);
}
```

is not compatible with IE.

If you want to support different browsers, write it like following:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'YourWebFontName';
    src: url('YourWebFontName.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('YourWebFontName.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('YourWebFontName.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('YourWebFontName.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('YourWebFontName.svg#YourWebFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

You may need some tools like [**Font Squirrel Generator**](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to generate the font files. Or you could just grab one from [**Google Fonts**](https://www.google.com/fonts).